# Android - How to tell is someone has pressed a SPINNER but not changed the visible item in it

Tags: android, listview, focus, spinner, try-catch

I have a spinner, which mostly works. If a user selects one of the items in it, the 'onItemSelected' routine catches it just fine.

But if a user clicks the same spinner, but does not change from the already visible item that it's currently displaying, the 'onItemSelected' routine just ignores it, and the logs show:-

**WARN/InputManagerService(577): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@437948b0**

I there anyway to capture someone doing this? The idea is that my spinner contains a list of names, and when a user selects one from the spinner, it gets added to a listview.

I could just add another button to get the name from the spinner, but, screen-space is already lacking and I'd rather not add anymore content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used the spinner but wouldn't it be possible to reset the spinners position in the onItemSelected routine? To some kind of null value that says "Please choose" or something.

Comment: The idea of having a 'park' heading in the spinner list has occurred to me, and it is quite easy to do using: -

spinnersname.setSelection(0); // 0 = heading/park position

but it seems like a bit of a bodge.

Answer (score 2):

This problem could be solved with overriding `Spinner.onClick()`, but this is buggy from android 3.0 and above ([`Spinner.onClick()` is called on 2.2 device, not called on 3.0 device](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16245)).

So the best solution is the `AlertDialog.Builder` as @adamp said.

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
// maybe get from resources 
CharSequence titles[] = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.titles);
builder.setItems(titles, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // add your code here               
  }
});
builder.create().show();
```

Comment: Heh. In my case, I want the spinner to fire an event because I'm using a secondary AlertDialog.Builder to make a sub-selection, but I need to retain the state of the top-level Spinner.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't actually want a Spinner, you're just using it for its popup dialog. You can create your own simple popup dialog like Spinner uses (as the result of an 'Add' button click in your UI perhaps?) by using [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html). Spinner uses `setSingleChoiceItems` followed by `show` on an `AlertDialog.Builder` to present its choices to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setOnItemClickListener)? If you implement your own `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` and pass it in as the argument to `mySpinner.setOnItemClickListener` method you'll be able to get ahold of the position of the selected item inside the `onItemClick` method

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.

Which is what I thought would happen, but thanks anyway. It's only possible to use 'onItemSelected'.

I think I'll go withh the 'park position' idea from softarn. But thanks for your suggestion.